# R CMD check on rstudio stopped working

Tags: r, cmd, build, rstudio

I am able to build R packages by "R CMD build" and "R CMD check" on the command prompt and it works just fine. I have also used the built in options in rstudio. But recently, when I use the "build & reload" option, it builds the package ok, but freezes up at the "reload" option. The same package passes build and check options on the command prompt. Any thoughts on what might be causing rstudio to freeze up?

Thanks,

Comment: What's your "Restore .RData at Startup" setting set to?

Comment: Restore .RData into workspace at startup is "unchecked".